# Setting up VS Code for use with Django, Apache, virtualenv on a remote server

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code, virtualenv, vscode-remote

we have a django project on a development server which is running within a virtual environment. I was hoping to be able to use VS Code for development from my local PC, but I am not sure if I am able to or not.  It seems like something that would make sense to do!

I think I have managed to set the interpreter as the virtualenv on the server using UNC paths and have activated it, but when I try to run manage.py to create a new app, I get No module named 'django' which perhaps suggested the virtualenv hasn't activate properly?

Is it possible to use VS Code in this way?

thanks,
Phil

Answer (score 0):

You can try extension named "[Remote-SSH](https://vscode:extension/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh)"

[image]

You can edit and debug on a remote machine with VS Code just like you could if the source code was local.

You can alos refer to the [document](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh-tutorial) of vscode for more details.